# how to fix the width of the columns in the latex table?

Tags: tables

I have a table with long heading names. I want to fix the the width of the columns. When I do so the text flows out if the column. Any suggestion about fixing it.

Here is the example

```
\begin{table*}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
Image & Score  & here is a lot of text & agian a lot &a lot and a lot& and the same here\\ \hline
a \(left\) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ \hline
b \(right\)&  1 &1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You can use the `p{<width>}` column type, and use a `\parbox` for the table content.  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages as that will help to ensure that the solution actually solves your specific case.

Comment: @peter, thanks , this \parbox will be used with every cell's content?

Comment: Better if you compose a small example, and then we can show you how to use it.

Comment: @peter, here is an example

Comment: Related question: [alignment - How to center cell contents of a LaTeX table whose columns have fixed widths? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357798/how-to-center-cell-contents-of-a-latex-table-whose-columns-have-fixed-widths)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an example of using the `p{}` column type, or wrapping the contents in a `\parbox`:

[image]

For your specific example, since you want the data columns aligned as per the table heading you could use something like:

```
\newcommand*{\TitleParbox}[1]{\parbox[c]{1.75cm}{\raggedright #1}}%
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    Image & Score  & \parbox[c]{1.5cm}{\raggedright here is a lot of text} & \TitleParbox{again a lot} &\TitleParbox{a lot and a lot}& \TitleParbox{and the same here}\\ \hline
    a \(left\) & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ \hline
    b \(right\)&  1 &1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

which yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `showframe` package was used to show the margins on the page.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\Title}{A very long table heading}%
\newcommand*{\TitleInParbox}{\parbox[c]{0.3\linewidth}{\Title}}%

\begin{document}
\section{Tabular with left alignment}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\Title & \Title & \Title
\end{tabular}

\section{Using the p\{\} column type:}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth} p{0.3\linewidth} p{0.3\linewidth}}
\Title & \Title & \Title
\end{tabular}

\section{Using a parbox:}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\TitleInParbox & \TitleInParbox & \TitleInParbox
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to considering the methods mentioned in [@PeterGrill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51011/5001), you should also consider using a `tabularx` environment. It provides a column type called `X`, which is (in effect) a `p` column -- i.e., it allows line wrapping -- but lets you dispense with the tedium of having to calculate the column widths if you want to make the table fit inside a given width, say, `\textwidth`.

You may also want to think about giving your table a more "open" look. In the following screenshot, the first table follows the layout provided in your code (except that a `tabularx` environment is used, with a modified `X` column type for columns 3 thru 6), whereas the second table achieves the "open" look by getting rid of all vertical rules and using fewer, but well spaced, horizontal rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % ragged-right version of "X"
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Lots of vertical and horizontal rules\strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|r|L|L|L|L|}
\hline
Image & Score  & here is a lot of text & again a lot & a lot and a lot & and the same here \\ \hline
a \emph{left}  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ \hline
b \emph{right} &  1 &1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{No vertical rules; fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lrLLLL @{}}
\toprule
Image & Score  & here is a lot of text & again a lot & a lot and a lot & and the same here \\ \midrule
a \emph{left}  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
b \emph{right} &  1 &1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `RaggedRight` could be substituted by `RaggedLeft` or `Centering`. If it can be useful to anyone.